# Smooth scrolling of UITableView with GIF images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView in my app that displays animating GIF images that are downloaded from the web.

I've used background threads to download images from the web and [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache) to store images temporary on the device. While downloading the UI behaves as expected i.e. tableview scroll is smooth.

The problem arises when GIF images gets downloaded and start animating. The scroll is not smooth as all the graphic processing is done on main thread.

I've tried doing the GIF animation on background thread, but the results are unexpected as it takes long for the image to get loaded in UIImageView and start animating and a loader is shown.

One possible solution is to pause the animation when tableview is scrolling but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Can anyone explain me the implementation part or some other solution?

Thanks.

Here is my code to load the images in the cell:

```
+(void)loadImageInCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul), ^{
        [[TMCache sharedCache] objectForKey:[URL absoluteString]
                                      block:^(TMCache *cache, NSString *key, id object) {
                                          if (object) {
                                              [self setImageFromFileAtPath:(NSString *)object inCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          [self addLoadingInCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

                                          NSArray *strings = [[URL absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
                                          NSString *fileName;
                                          for (NSString *string in strings) {
                                              if ([string rangeOfString:@".gif"].location != NSNotFound) {
                                                  NSRange stopRange = [string rangeOfString:@".gif"];
                                                  fileName = [string substringToIndex:(stopRange.location + stopRange.length)];
                                                  break;
                                              }
                                          }
                                          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                                          NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                                          NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

                                          if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
                                              [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:filePath forKey:[URL absoluteString]];
                                              [self setImageFromFileAtPath:filePath inCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                                          NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
                                          NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

                                          if ([data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
                                              [self setImageFromFileAtPath:filePath inCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
                                              [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:filePath forKey:[URL absoluteString]];
                                          }
                                      }];
    });
}

+(void)setImageFromFileAtPath:(NSString *)path inCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self removeLoadingFromCell:(UIView *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            [[(UITableViewCell *)cell imageView] setImage:nil];
            [[(UITableViewCell *)cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:imageData]];
        } else {
            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[(UICollectionViewCell *)cell viewWithTag:1001];
            [imageView setImage:nil];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:imageData]];
        }
    });
}

+(void)addLoadingInCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityIndicator setTag:5001];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UITableViewCell *tableCell = (UITableViewCell *)cell;
            [activityIndicator setCenter:tableCell.imageView.center];
            [tableCell addSubview:activityIndicator];
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        });
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UICollectionViewCell *collectionCell = (UICollectionViewCell *)cell;
            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[collectionCell viewWithTag:1001];
            [activityIndicator setCenter:imageView.center];
            [imageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        });
    }
}

+(void)removeLoadingFromCell:(UIView *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIView *activityView = [cell viewWithTag:5001];
        if (activityView) {
            [activityView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    });
}
```

Images are animated from the following code:

```
static int delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex(CGImageSourceRef const source, size_t const i) {
    int delayCentiseconds = 1;
    CFDictionaryRef const properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    if (properties) {
        CFDictionaryRef const gifProperties = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary);
        CFRelease(properties);
        if (gifProperties) {
            CFNumberRef const number = CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime);
            // Even though the GIF stores the delay as an integer number of centiseconds, ImageIO “helpfully” converts that to seconds for us.
            delayCentiseconds = (int)lrint([fromCF number doubleValue] * 100);
        }
    }
    return delayCentiseconds;
}

static void createImagesAndDelays(CGImageSourceRef source, size_t count, CGImageRef imagesOut[count], int delayCentisecondsOut[count]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        imagesOut[i] = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
        delayCentisecondsOut[i] = delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex(source, i);
    }
}

static int sum(size_t const count, int const *const values) {
    int theSum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        theSum += values[i];
    }
    return theSum;
}

static int pairGCD(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return pairGCD(b, a);
    while (true) {
        int const r = a % b;
        if (r == 0)
            return b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
}

static int vectorGCD(size_t const count, int const *const values) {
    int gcd = values[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        // Note that after I process the first few elements of the vector, `gcd` will probably be smaller than any remaining element.  By passing the smaller value as the second argument to `pairGCD`, I avoid making it swap the arguments.
        gcd = pairGCD(values[i], gcd);
    }
    return gcd;
}

static NSArray *frameArray(size_t const count, CGImageRef const images[count], int const delayCentiseconds[count], int const totalDurationCentiseconds) {
    int const gcd = vectorGCD(count, delayCentiseconds);
    size_t const frameCount = totalDurationCentiseconds / gcd;
    UIImage *frames[frameCount];
    for (size_t i = 0, f = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        UIImage *const frame = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:images[i]];
        for (size_t j = delayCentiseconds[i] / gcd; j > 0; --j) {
            frames[f++] = frame;
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frames count:frameCount];
}

static void releaseImages(size_t const count, CGImageRef const images[count]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        CGImageRelease(images[i]);
    }
}

static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(CGImageSourceRef const source) {
    size_t const count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);
    CGImageRef images[count];
    int delayCentiseconds[count]; // in centiseconds
    createImagesAndDelays(source, count, images, delayCentiseconds);
    int const totalDurationCentiseconds = sum(count, delayCentiseconds);
    NSArray *const frames = frameArray(count, images, delayCentiseconds, totalDurationCentiseconds);
    UIImage *const animation = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:frames duration:(NSTimeInterval)totalDurationCentiseconds / 100.0];
    releaseImages(count, images);
    return animation;
}

static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceRef source) {
    if (source) {
        UIImage *const image = animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(source);
        CFRelease(source);
        return image;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:(NSData *)data {
    return animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceCreateWithData(toCF data, NULL));
}

+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(toCF url, NULL));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are using a lot of blocks and they increase the use of memory tenfold.... U can easily do without them here ...

Comment: @IronManGill I've removed an extra block from +loadImageInCell:atIndexPath:forURL: the performance is better but still not upto the mark. The solution I guess is to get notification when tableview scrolls, stop animating when scrolling start and start animating when scrolling stops. But how can I implement the same?

Comment: See anyways when you scroll the number of cells you are being shown are reloaded simultaneously .... So u neednt bother that the gif images are working in the whole table they should be working on the number of cells that you are viewing...